# Can't edit boot commands in VMware for Android x86

Tags: 9.0-pie, android-x86

I'm attempting to install  Android x86 from https://www.fosshub.com/Android-x86.html following the steps on https://hackmd.io/@StanS/Android-x86, and after getting to the point where I can reboot and boot into the OS, I go to edit the boot command for step 4. I hit e twice, but then I can't change the boot command. It just gives me a line with out the string that I need to edit. on the previous page, it has the string listed, but everything I search for just says it should be there. [image: Image of what I am getting instead of the option i should be getting]

Answer (score 0):

You need to type reboot

Or you can watch this tutorial on Youtube
https://youtu.be/nFtNKY1g6Lc?si=HzynNrGjrZaSI414

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).